# Как Excel "понимает", какой в пределах какого диапазона сортировать?

Tags: excel, сортировка, vba, фильтрация

Мне нужно сортировать таблицу по четырём столбцам. Часто. Поэтому пишу макрос. Тот, что написал я (не буду приводить тут его код, потому что: 1. вопрос его не касается; 2. не хочу "раздувать" вопрос), не работает до конца.
По этой причине я записал макрос макро рекордером, найдя в группе "Редактирование" Инструмент "Сортировка и фильтр" и кликнув "Настраиваемая сортировка". Добавил три уровня к существующему одному и выбрал нужные мне столбцы.
Вот что получилось на выходе:

```
Sub macro_record()
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").AutoFilter.Sort. _
        SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").AutoFilter.Sort. _
        SortFields.Add Key:=Range("A2:A1000000"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:= _
        xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").AutoFilter.Sort. _
        SortFields.Add Key:=Range("C2:C1000000"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:= _
        xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").AutoFilter.Sort. _
        SortFields.Add Key:=Range("E2:E1000000"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:= _
        xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortTextAsNumbers
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").AutoFilter.Sort. _
        SortFields.Add Key:=Range("G2:G1000000"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:= _
        xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").AutoFilter. _
        Sort
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
End Sub
```

**Вопрос в следующем**: как Excel "понимает", какой именно диапазон нужно сортировать? Иными словами, в какой строке кода программа передаёт компьютеру адрес диапазона для сортировки?

Comment: Сортировка выполняется в диапазоне AutoFilter. См. AutoFilter.Range.Address

Comment: Как я понимаю, задание этого диапазона вообще не вошло в записанный макро рекордером код...

Comment: Да, столбцы определяются при создании автофильтра. А вот строки (вернее, нижний предел) может быть (и даже должен быть) и динамически определяемым. Но не копался.

Comment: Я однажды пробовал применять подобный макрос, только для случая с сортировкой по одному столбцу, к таблице с уже созданным автофильтром. В итоге, отсортировался только один столбец и соответствие между ячейками было нарушено.

Comment: Ну так проверяй диапазон автофильтра. А ещё лучше - удаляй и пересоздавай его. С автоматическим расширением диапазона.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Об автофильтре** (закладка *Данные-Фильтр*)

Диапазон, который попадает под действие автофильтра, зависит от расположения данных и  диапазона, выделенного перед установкой фильтра.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Самое простое (вар.1): выделен весь диапазон с данными - в фильтре все выделенные, включая строки, которые расположены ниже пустой строки (разрыв данных).

Выделен не весь диапазон с данными. В фильтр попадают данные всех столбцов выделенного диапазона (вар.2), а вот со строками начинается... Нужно понимать, что автофильтр сам старается определить заголовки и диапазон для фильтрации.

Выделена одна ячейка в диапазоне с данными (вар.3) - в фильтре весь диапазон ячеек с данными, ограниченный пустыми столбцами и строками (т.е. если ниже пустой строки есть данные, они в фильтр не попадают). То же, если выделен диапазон, который включает все столбцы с данными и первая строка которого - это первая строка с данными (вар.4).

Выделена одна ячейка, вокруг которой нет данных - в фильтре нет фильтруемых ячеек, только заголовок (вар.5)

Выделен диапазон не с первой строки с данными (вар.6, вар.7)- строки выше в фильтр не попадают.

Если ячейка пустая и есть контакт со строкой выше, в которой есть данные, в фильтр попадет и строка с выделенной ячейкой (вар.8, вар.9)

Если ячейка пустая и нет контакта с ячейками, в которых есть данные, автофильтр не установится (вар.10).

и т.д.

**О сортировке** (закладка *Данные-Сортировка*)

Здесь можно задать настраиваемую сортировку: очередность (по столбцам или строкам), порядок (по возрастанию, по убыванию, по списку), вид (по значению, цвету).

Есть несколько нюансов.

Если нужный диапазон не выделен, диапазон фильтрации определяется автоматически (почти как в автофильтре) - относительно активной ячейки.

Если выделенный диапазон граничит с невыделенными данными, нужно подтвердить диапазон фильтрации (расширить диапазон или оставить для сортировки выделенный).

Галка, отвечающая за то, будут ли в сортируемом диапазоне заголовки: если галка снята, под фильтрацию попадет первая строка выделенного диапазона (даже если это заголовки автофильтра)

Все эти моменты нужно учитывать при записи макроса.

```
Sub macro_record()
    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        With .Range("A1:G2000")
            .Parent.AutoFilterMode = False
            .AutoFilter
        End With
        
        With .AutoFilter.Sort
            With .SortFields
                .Clear
                .Add Key:=Range("A2:A2000"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
                                Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
                .Add Key:=Range("C2:C2000"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
                                Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
                .Add Key:=Range("E2:E2000"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
                                Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortTextAsNumbers
                .Add Key:=Range("G2:G2000"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
                                Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
            End With

            .Header = xlYes: .MatchCase = False
            .Apply
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Указываем диапазон (`.Range("A1:G2000")`); для исключения ошибки при установке фильтра снимаем фильтр(`.AutoFilterMode = False`); ставим фильтр (`.AutoFilter`); задаем параметры сортировки (`.SortFields`); заголовки - да, есть (`.Header = xlYes`); регистр учитывать не нужно (`.MatchCase = False`); просим применить заданную сортировку к нашему объекту (`.AutoFilter.Sort.Apply`)

Но так ли нужен автофильтр? Сортировать можно без него. Заодно добавим определение высоты диапазона (переменную `LastRow`)

```
Sub macro_record()
    Dim LastRow As Long
    
    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        LastRow = .UsedRange.Rows.Count - .UsedRange.Row + 1
 
        With .Sort
            With .SortFields
                .Clear
                .Add Key:=Range("A2:A" & LastRow), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
                                Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
                .Add Key:=Range("C2:C" & LastRow), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
                                Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
                .Add Key:=Range("E2:E" & LastRow), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
                                Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortTextAsNumbers
                .Add Key:=Range("G2:G" & LastRow), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
                                Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
            End With
            
            .SetRange Range("A1:G" & LastRow)
            .Header = xlYes: .MatchCase = False
            .Apply
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Диапазон сортировки задается строкой

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SetRange Range("A1:G" & LastRow)
```

А так как указано, что заголовки есть (`Sort.Header = xlYes`), то сортируемые диапазоны указаны со второй строки.

Показанные коды работают на активном листе

Comment: Спасибо за подробную справку! Кое-что из неё интуитивно (точнее, эвристически) понятно, но есть и новое для меня.

Как говорится, какой вопрос, такой и ответ. Формально, на вопрос вы ответили, поэтому галку ставлю. Но мою задачу это не решает, поэтому буду писать новый вопрос... Возможно, вы же на него и ответите)

Comment: Добавил примеры макросов

Comment: Ого, спасибо за код с подробными объяснениями! Возьму на вооружение, по успешному выполнению доложу) Автофильтр действительно нужен, поскольку между сортировками таблица должна фильтроваться. Ещё раз огромное спасибо! UPD. Возможно, вы имели в виду, что коды работают в активной **книге** на листе "Sheet1"? Anyway, с этим я справлюсь.

Comment: Нет. И книга активна, и лист активный. Если работать на неактивном листе, в коде нужно дополнить ссылки на диапазоны ссылкой на лист.

Comment: Всё работает, корректность сортировки проверил по нескольким столбцам, сравнив построчно с архивной копией таблицы. Но выводить на продакшн данные, отсортированные макросом, всё равно сс#котно))

Comment: Тогда вручную. 100% гарантия :) :) :)  Если есть сомнения - написать макрос проверки правильности сортировки.

Comment: Обещал - докладываю. Уже больше месяца как сортирую автоматически. До макроса проверки правильности работы макроса руки пока не дошли, но со стороны пользователя претензий к правильности данных ни разу не было.